# Apache Module mod_proxy_wstunnel not working

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, botpress

I have a website running at http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000 and it runs [Botpress][1]
In order to have it running via HTTPS I made an Apache reverse proxy configuration:
My file looks like:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass "/"  "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/"
ProxyPass "/socket.io/" "ws://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/socket.io/"
ProxyPassReverse "/socket.io/" "ws://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/socket.io/"
```

Now if I go to https://botpress.mywebsite.com I see the Botstrap admin interface working however when I login I see an error in the browser's console showing:

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://botpress.mywebsite.com/socket.io/?visitorId=_GUWkjNu-VH9XpE3DpO76PxD&token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9....&transport=websocket. web.100.....94b.js:2:6616130
was interrupted while the page was loading.

Is there something wrong in my config file with the ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse for socket.io?

Thanks.
[1]: https://botpress.com/

Comment: I made it working by adding this to my config file : RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/$1 [P,L]

Answer (score 1):

i spent a few days on this. I found the problem was really in the order things were added in conf file.

```
‘RewriteEngine On’
‘RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling [OR]’
‘RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /socket.io/socket.io.js’
‘RewriteRule /socket.io/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/socket.io/$1 [P]’
‘ProxyPass /socket.io/ ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/‘
‘ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ ws://localhost:8082/socket.io/‘
‘ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/‘
‘ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000’
‘ProxyPreserveHost on’
```

Comment: you have to have the /socket.io/ above the normal / http is generally what i’m saying!